# Very brutal swap using template, xor and pointers to to the memory

Tags: c++, templates, memory, swap, xor

What are the most threats of using such implementation of swap? Besides thread safety and poor optimisation. When does it fail (counterexample)?

```
template<typename T>
void swapViaMemory(T& left, T& right) {
    if(&left == &right) { return ; }

    unsigned int tSize = sizeof(T);
    unsigned char* lPtr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&left);
    unsigned char* rPtr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&right);

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < tSize; ++i) {
        *(lPtr + i) ^= *(rPtr + i);
        *(rPtr + i) ^= *(lPtr + i);
        *(lPtr + i) ^= *(rPtr + i);
    }
}
```

Sorry for grammar mistakes, and misspellings (=

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `T` contains a member which is a pointer or reference to another of its members this will fail (assuming the intent is for the pointer / reference member to always point / refer to the data member belonging to that instance).

```
struct foo
{
  foo() : i(), ref_i(i), ptr_i(&i) {}
  int i;
  int& ref_i;
  int *ptr_i;
};
```

If two `foo` objects, say `f1` & `f2` are swapped using `swapViaMemory`, after swapping, `f1.ref_i` and `f1.ptr_i` will refer / point to `f2.i` and vice versa. Also, in case of the reference member, this invokes undefined behavior since it's illegal to re-seat a reference.

Comment: This isn't true for pointer members unless you expand on what 'this will fail' means.

Comment: @Praetorian Ohh, I like that. Pointers are gonna cross-point between members of the swapped objects.

Answer (score 5):

It invokes undefined behavior if T is not a trivially copyable type.

Answer (score 4):

It fails in the conveying of intent.

Which is the primary purpose of code.

```
template<typename T>
   typename std::enable_if<std::is_pod<T>, void>::type 
   swapViaMemory(T& left, T& right) 
{
    using std::swap;

    swap(left, right);
}
```

Comment: Right, until your "intent" turns out not be slow as a dog in practice, in which case your customers don't give two hoots about your "intent".  Not saying that's the case here, but in general, the primary purpose of code is to compile to machine language so that we *can solve problems*.  Clarity should always be strived for, but it should also always take a back seat to getting the job done well and quickly.

Comment: @EdS. This is entirely not the case here. Even `std::copy` will optimize straight into SSE-enabled `memcpy`/`memmov` if the valuetype is POD. You gotta profile. And then the question gets morphed into: "can I use this hack ***here***", not "when should I ***not*** use this hack"

Comment: Agreed, which is why I qualified my comment.  I was concerned with the statement that *"[Intent] is the primary purpose of code."*, which I strongly disagree with.  I also meant to type "turns out *to be* slow as a dog" above.

Answer (score 1):

Say for:

```
struct B{ 
   virtual ~B() {}
};
struct X : B
{
   int x;
   ~X() { std::cout << x; }
};
struct Y : B
{

};

//...
X x = X(); 
Y y;
swapViaMemory<B>(x,y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides being horribly obfuscated it fails if the cast of left and right point to the same address.

Since `a^a = 0` (which is what you use for this 'trick')

If `left == right` (and lets assume it's a 1 byte entity containing `'a'`
Then you will do:

```
a^a = 0
0^a = a
a^a = 0
```

Comment: How so? - notice it does nothing for equality.